# .NET how to disable FluentValidation with formHelper on certain submit button

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation, form-helpers

I'm using [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#clientside-validation) with [FormHelper](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper) in order to validate my form **using ajax**.
My form has 2 submit buttons:

1. Default one **that should run validation** (Save method in controller has [FormValidator] annotation)
2. Second one (calls another controlers' method) **should have validation disabled**  (Save method in controller has no validation annotation)

At this moment **both buttons** do POST call to Save method so validation run in both cases. If I remove FormHelper validation tags, client calls correct methods but there is no validation off course.

What should I do in order to enable validation **only for one button**?

View:

```
<form id="myFrom" asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="Save" method="post" asp-formhelper="true">
    <label asp-for="MyField" class="form-label">My field: </label>
    <input asp-for="MyField" class="form-control"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="MyField" class="text-danger"></span>              
    
    <input type="submit" value="POST with validation">      
    <input type="submit" asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="AnotherAction" value="Post without validation">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController
{
    [HttpPost, FormValidator]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Save(MyViewModel vm)
    {        
        //do sth
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AnotherAction(MyViewModel vm)
    {
        //do another actions
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is client-side validation, server-side or both? What you want to disable in your case?